Running into a suspense boundary error for useSearchParams() hook while trying to build web project
'use client';

import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

export default function Watch() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const videoPrefix = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/koranimal-yt-processed-videos/';
  const videoSrc = searchParams.get('v');

  return (
    <div>
       <h1>Watch Page</h1>
       <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        {videoSrc ? (
          <video controls src={videoPrefix + videoSrc} />
        ) : (
          <div>Video not found.</div>
        )}
      </Suspense>
     </div>
  );
}

Originally I didn't include the suspense boundaries and my project built correctly. I'm following along with NeetCode's tutorial and he didn't have to include the suspense boundaries. Upon trying to build a new docker image I get the errors

Generating static pages (3/6) [==  ]heartbeats undefined

and

⨯ useSearchParams() should be wrapped in a suspense boundary at page "/watch"

Upon doing some research I included the suspense boundaries but am still having the same issue.
Tried using the suspense boundaries in different positions to fix the error to know avail. Also looked at similar cases on github and stackexchange but none of the solutions I found were able to fix / change the error code. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling node modules  which also did not help the issue.

Is your Watch component a server component or just a component that is rendered elsewhere inside a page component? If that is a page component, I do not think you have to import the useSearchParams hook. You have access to the search params through props. Please see the docs here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params#static-rendering

Based on this https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/missing-suspense-with-csr-bailout
the Suspense component must wrap the entire component that uses the useSearchParams() otherwise the page will be blank, since the hook is a client-side hook based on its definition

useSearchParams is a Client Component hook that lets you read the current URL's query string.

So, using the approach mentioned in the documentation would solve your problem:
"use client";

import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

import React, { Suspense } from "react";

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
      <ShowVideo />
    </Suspense>
  );
}

function ShowVideo() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const videoPrefix =
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/koranimal-yt-processed-videos/";
  const videoSrc = searchParams.get("v");

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Watch Page</h1>
      <video controls src={videoPrefix + videoSrc} />
    </div>
  );
}

